# Need to find reports on Search. E.g. Top searched keyword, categories

Tags: azure, saas, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure search where it creates index on my database tables and shows results as expected.

Now I have a requirement where I need to find-out what are the words or items users have searched most or what was the pick time for search.

Is it possible to find any such reports with Azure Search? 
Either by its portal or using the API or Code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Azure Search team, thanks for using the service. Currently it's not possible, however, we understand the importance of this feature and we're working to deliver it. No exact dates yet. For now, you'd have to collect and aggregate the information you need on the client side.

For feature request like this, feel free to use our User Voice page to help us prioritize work: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search